# Shuffling an array without built in functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shuffle

Trying to shuffle an array without using built in functions.

```
def shuffle2():
    lis = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
    print (lis)
    x = random.randint (0,len (lis)-1)
    y = random.randint (0,len (lis)-1)
    z = lis[x], lis[y] = lis[y], lis[x]#flips the elements around

 shuffle2()
```

So far it switches two elements around once, however I need it to shuffle the whole array rather than just two positions.

output:
      [5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12]
      [11, 6, 7, 10, 5, 12]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean without any built-in functions other than `randint()`? And do you want the entire array to have random rearrangements of its elements?

Comment: FWIW, the [implementation of `random.shuffle`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l277) is available for anyone to read -- And it's fairly simple to understand ...

Comment: `for` loops. they save the day when you need to repeat something :-)

Comment: if possible no built in functions including randint but I havent figured out how to do it yet, which is why randint is still on there. yes the entire array.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard but every time I repeat, it repeats the same thing...for example if I did put it in for loop it would print the same element change n times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
import bisect
import random

def shuffle(lis):
    newlis = []
    temp = []
    for i in lis:
        x = random.random()
        #put x into temp and put i into the same place in newlis
        n = bisect.bisect(temp,x)
        temp.insert(n,x)
        newlis.insert(n,i)
    return newlis

lis=[5,6,7,10,11,12]
>>> shuffle(lis)
[6, 12, 10, 11, 7, 5]
```

The method essentially generate random numbers and puts them into a sorted list (temp). The items is lis are put into a newlis in the same way, which has the effect of sorting it.

You, of course, can write your own bisect, or use a more trivial search function quite easily...

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def shuffle2():
    i = 1
    lis = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
    print (lis)
    while i < len(lis):
        x = random.randint (0,len (lis)-1)
        y = random.randint (0,len (lis)-1)
        z = lis[x], lis[y] = lis[y], lis[x]
        i = i + 1
        #flips the elements around

    print (lis)
```